# What's going on with you?/What's happening with you?

Tags: expressions

"We don't talk about you behind your back. **What's going on with you?**/**What's happening with you?** Why are you being so paranoid?"

Can I use "What's going on with you?" or "What's happening with you?" to mean something like "What's wrong with you?" or is it only used to mean "How are you?" ? And do you think it's perfectly natural in the context above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "What's going on with you?" to imply that there's something wrong with you in that context. It can be used for a variety of things depending on the context.

Example: "Hey, Jack? What's going on with you?" "Why would you do that? What's going on with you?"

The phrase itself is natural to use in the context that you used.